# Update Draggable UI for touchsxcreen dragging

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, mouse

I have a slider of images that currently responds via a mouse event jscript. i am wondering if anybody knows how i would introduce either jsmobile or pep or maybe even touchpunch to enable the draggable function on mobile devices. at present the responsive test on Dev tools works in the responsive view, but if i use ny of the mobile or others it just highlights the images and does not drag them... im really new to jquery so i am needing to know how to implement such plugins . thank you for any advice.. here is the current jscript mouse event code...

Thank you in advance for any workarounds..

```
  <script>

        var selected = null, // Object of the element to be moved
        x_pos = 0, // Stores x & y coordinates of the mouse pointer
        x_elem = 0; // Stores top, left values (edge) of the element


           function _drag_init(elem) {
            // Store the object of the element which needs to be moved
            selected = elem;
            x_elem = x_pos - selected.offsetLeft
        }

        document.all                        
        function _move_elem(e) {
            x_pos = document.all ? window.event.clientX : e.pageX;



           var windw = window.innerWidth-174 
            var windww = window.innerWidth 


            if (x_pos-x_elem > windw) {bakit();}

            if (selected !== null) {
                selected.style.left = (x_pos-x_elem) + 'px'}
            }


            function _destroy() {
                selected = null;    
            }

            document.getElementById('layout').onmousedown = function () {
                _drag_init(this);
                    return false;
                }
                document.onmousemove = _move_elem;
                document.onmouseup = _destroy;

                function bakit(){
                    selected = null;
                }
    </script>

l8r---------------------------------------->
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var el = document.getElementById('drag'); 

      el.addEventListener("touchstart", handleStart, false);
      el.addEventListener("touchend", handleEnd, false);
      el.addEventListener("touchcancel", handleCancel, false);
      el.addEventListener("touchleave", handleEnd, false);
      el.addEventListener("touchmove", handleMove, false);

      function handleStart(event) {
          // Handle the start of the touch
      }

      // ^ Do the same for the rest of the events

    </script>
```